# Set with positive relative measure in all intervals

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A$ be a (Borel-)measurable subset of $[0,1]$.Let $\lambda$ denote Lebesgue measure. Is it possible that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that for all intervals $I \subset [0,1]$ we have
$$
\lambda(A \cap I) \geq c \lambda(I),
$$
other than in the trivial case when $\lambda(A)=1$?

If the answer is "yes", then what is an example of such a set?

Comment: no: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem

Comment: Yes, thank you, I probably have seen this theorem during my education, but still it took me a moment to realize how it solves the problem stated above.

Answer (score 2):

No, the situation you describe is impossible if $A$ is not of full measure.

Suppose $B=[0,1]\setminus A$ has measure $m>0$. There is a cover of $B$ by open intervals of total length smaller than $\frac{m}{1-c}$. It follows that $B$ has density above $1-c$ in one of those intervals, so $A$ has density below $c$ in that interval.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought that this might be a standard problem, but with measurable sets you never know which weird things they are able to do. Thanks again!